# How do I group by month when I have data in a time range, accurate up to the second?

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I'd like to ask if there's a way to group my data by months in this case:

I have table of orders, with order Ids in a column and the dates the orders were created in another.

For example,

```
orderId | creationDate
58111   | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
58111   | 2017-01-12 00:00:00
58232   | 2017-01-31 00:00:00
62882   | 2017-02-21 00:00:00
90299   | 2017-03-20 00:00:00
```

I need to find the number of unique orderIds, grouped by month. Normally this would be simple, but with my creationDates accurate to the second, I have no idea how to segment them into months. Ideally, this is what I'd obtain:

```
creationMonth | count_orderId
January       | 2  
February      | 1
March         | 1
```

Comment: table definition ?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select count( distinct orderId ), year( creationDate ), month( creationDate ) 
from my_table group by year( creationDate ), month( creationDate )
```